# Export Chrome MV3 extension to Firefox MV3

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've created a test extension using manifest V3 that works in chrome

`manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`content.js`:

```js
alert('test')
```

I tried running

```bash
web-ext run --firefox-preview
```

A browser window opens, but the extension is not working...
Using the `--verbose` option I find these errors

```
 Firefox stderr: [Parent 14212, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_win.cc:167
 Firefox stderr: JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 58: Error: Can't find profile directory.
 Firefox stdout: console.error: services.settings:
 Firefox stdout: main/whats-new-panel Signature failed  InvalidSignatureError: Invalid content signature (main/whats-new-panel)
 Firefox stdout: console.error: services.settings:
 Firefox stdout: main/whats-new-panel local data was corrupted
console.warn: services.settings: main/whats-new-panel Signature verified failed. Retry from scratch
```

```
 Firefox stdout: console.error: services.settings:
 Firefox stdout: main/addons-manager-settings Signature failed again InvalidSignatureError: Invalid content signature (main/addons-manager-settings)
 Firefox stdout: console.error: services.settings:
 Firefox stdout: Message: InvalidSignatureError: Invalid content signature (main/addons-manager-settings)
  Stack:
    InvalidSignatureError@resource://services-settings/RemoteSettingsClient.jsm:169:5
_validateCollectionSignature@resource://services-settings/RemoteSettingsClient.jsm:977:13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's stated in [this](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/blog-post-manifest-v3-in-firefox-recap-next-steps/97372/7) article,
"The issue is about host permissions, in MV3, they’re not granted automatically on install, but instead user needs to grant them at some point. Depending on what’s appropriate for your extension, you could ask the user using promise.request() , or they can grant it by going to about:addons, selecting your addon, and flipping the toggle in the permissions tab."